# How to background service running with mobile network in sleep mode?

Tags: java, android

I'm create background service to update location. It work well with wifi in sleep mode but when i use mobile network in sleep mode, my background service not update location. What should i do to run background service with mobile network in sleep mode?

I using Service library and update location to server.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocationService extends Service {

double latitude=0f;
double longitude=0f;
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 300000;
float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;
public ServerHelper serverHelper = new ServerHelper();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("onCreate: ", "create");
    initializeLocationManager();

    try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    locationListeners[0]);

    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    }
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onBind: ", "bind");
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("onStartCommand: ", "startcommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("onDestroy: ", "destroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null) {
        for (LocationListener locationListener : locationListeners) 
{
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
private class LocationListener implements 
android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLocation;
    Calendar calendar;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", 
Locale.getDefault());

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged: ", "locationChange");
        calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String time = dateFormat.format(date);

        mLocation.set(location);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        String latlng = latitude+","+longitude;
serverHelper.updateLocation(getApplicationContext(),latlng,time);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle 
extras) {
        Log.d("onStatusChanged: ", "status");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("onProviderEnabled: ", "proEnabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("onProviderDisabled: ", "proDisabled");
    }
    LocationListener(String provider) {
        mLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
}
LocationListener[] locationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        //new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
private void initializeLocationManager() {
    if (locationManager == null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
}
```

when i use mobile network in sleep mode. onLocationChanged can't call

Comment: An always running service basically won't work in modern Android due to battery optimizations.  I'd start by questioning why you need such frequent location updates in the background

Comment: the only way to make it work in background is asquiring a wakelock. Not sure about Android p

Comment: @GabeSechan i need check current location of user every 5 minutes. when i use wifi it working well but change mobile network it don't work on sleep mode.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i will try it. do you have another solution? thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a background service for something like that. Modern Android versions will kill the service after 15 minutes and you can't restart it unless your app is running in the foreground. Android tries to preserve battery life and you should try to support it.

Here are possible solutions:

1. Use AlarmManager to setup a repeating alarm. Android may decide to delay your alarm in certain situations, e.g. if the phone is sleeping.
2. Use JobScheduler to schedule a recurring job which updates the location. This requires Android L.
3. Use the Android Jetpack WorkManager. This combines the above two solutions and picks the best way under the hood. This is the preferred solution. Check [this page out](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work) to see how to schedule recurring work.
4. If you really want to use a background service for continuously updating the location, you need to create foreground service by calling `startForeground()` in your service and passing a notification. This notification will be shown to the user as long as your service is running but Android won't kill it. This solution is not recommended as it drains the battery faster and the user will notice due to the ongoing notification.

The main pattern is this: don't keep your app running but schedule the location updates with one of the above solutions. Android became very restrictive with background services over the last couple of versions and forces you to adopt the new mechanics by killing your background services and not letting allow you to restart them unless your app is in the foreground. This preserves battery. I'd recommend to not update the location more than every 15 minutes.

Comment: thanks bro. i know that. but my problem is why when use wifi it running well in sleep mode but mobile network not? pls explain to me.

Comment: This might be due to the device you are using. I'm not aware of an Android default behaviour that would explain that besides the 15 minutes cap. Many manufacturers implement their own energy savings features (e.g. Samsung is very aggressive) and they are less well documented. What's the device/OS you have the issue on? Did you try solution 4 and use a foreground service?

Comment: i'm using Samsung A3 2016, android 7.0. I try solution 4 and work well with mobile data in sleep mode. Thank you so muchhhh bro, you save my day. But i'm worrying about battery problem as your mean. Sorry bro my English not good.

Comment: The best solution is WorkManager. Give it a shot. Usually if the phone goes to sleep it's not used, so usually location updates are not that important. In the end: test it out and check in the system settings how much battery is consumed. **Can you please accept my answer if 4 worked?**

Comment: how to accept your answer? I'm new contributor, sorry about that.